# What is the influence of initial state in sequence generated from a markov chain?

Tags: r, markov-process, laplace-smoothing

For thousands of item, I have observations about their state (a letter) for 9 timestep.
From that, I build a transition matrix (`RotationMatrix` by  couting their occurence) and used the markovchain package in R to build a chain, then simulate a sequence of "observation" from it, then fitting a new chain onto the sequence and extracting the "simulated transition matrix".

```
LetterList<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I") 
RotationMatrix
                  A      B      C      D      E       F      G       H    I
A              0.66   0.010  0.030   0.020  0.020   0.050  0.030  0.090   0.090
B              0.01   0.850  0.010   0.040  0.010   0.010  0.040  0.020   0.010
C              0.10   0.010  0.740   0.100  0.010   0.010  0.010  0.010   0.010
D              0.01   0.001  0.001   0.983  0.001   0.001  0.001  0.001   0.001
E              0.56   0.010  0.080   0.070  0.060   0.010  0.040  0.090   0.080
F              0.87   0.010  0.010   0.010  0.010   0.010  0.010  0.040   0.030
G              0.27   0.010  0.030   0.050  0.010   0.010  0.560  0.040   0.020
H              0.88   0.010  0.010   0.010  0.010   0.010  0.020  0.020   0.030
I              0.83   0.010  0.010   0.010  0.020   0.010  0.020  0.080   0.010
 
  
MCRotation<-new("markovchain", states = LetterList, byrow=TRUE, transitionMatrix=RotationMatrix, name="LetterRotation")
    
    RotationSimulated<-rmarkovchain(n=10000,object=MCRotation, t0= "A")
    
RotationfittedLAPLACE<-markovchainFit(data=RotationSimulated, method ="laplace", laplacian=0.01, name = "t0A_Simulated")
```

My goal is to have THE transition probability for each LETTER to any other LETTER.
What is the influence of the initial state `t0` in the simulated sequence and the chain estimated from it ?
Should I run the markovchain several times with each LETTER as initial state? And then using the corresponding line (corresponding letter from initial state) in the transition matrix ?

Thanks in advance,
Sarah

Comment: If I understand correctly, then your matrix `RotationMatrix` is already the transition matrix in the sense that the transition e.g. from A to B is given by the matrix element in line A and column B. So why do you want to use a simulation and then fitting to obtain something you already have?

Comment: Hi @Frank, yes, `RotationMatrix` is built from observations by simply tallying the occurence of transition from one state to another. I want to use a Bayeasian approach to take into account the data uncertainty by resimulating the observations x thousands of times and extract a transition matrix from it. What is your opinion on that ?

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the transition matrix of the Markov chain, you just observe all the transitions many times and then compute the belonging transition frequencies which are the approximations for the transition probabilities. That is what you have done in creating the matrix `RotationMatrix`.

How good are those approximations? If you can presume that those transition probabilities don't change and that you also have no measurement errors, the confidence intervals for their estimations can be [computed in several ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). They depend, of course, on the number of observed transitions.

However, if you suspect that those transition probabilities are varying and/or that your measurements have some error, those formulae might not apply anymore. In this case, you could just compute the estimations several times (e.g. using [bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics))) and then take the sample variance.

Finally, your question about how the start value affects the simulated sequence. Of course, the sequence depends on the starting point, but if the Markov chain is [ergodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Ergodicity), the statistics are independent of the starting value.